Why does QPE still produce phase eigenvalues in HHL even though it operates on non-eigenvectors?
I'm trying to understand mathematical intuition of HHL algorithm using original paper (arXiv)
For now I stuck at the part of Phase estimation. If I understand correctly, if vector b is the eigenvector of the operator, then the phase estimation produces phase of a certain eigenvalue of this operator at the second register and does not change the first register (with vector b) due to the definition of eigenvalues and eigenvectors. But what happens in the HHL algorithm? Why QPE does still produces the phase eigenvalues even if b is not and eigenvector anymore? Does the vector b itself changes or what do the words

decompose $|b\rangle$ in the eigenvector basis

mean?
Additionally, what does the equation below mean, how was it created and where the variables come from - this is not clear for me also.
$$
|\Psi_0\rangle:=\sqrt{\frac2T}\sum_{\tau=0}^{T-1}\sin\frac{\pi(\tau+\frac12)}T|\tau\rangle
$$

Let the eigenvectors of the phase estimation be $|\phi_i\rangle$. There are lots of these (an entire orthonormal basis). You know that what the phase estimation achieves is
$$
|\phi_i\rangle \longrightarrow |\phi_i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle
$$
where $\theta_i$ is the vector that contains the information about the eigenvalue.
So, if your input state is $|b\rangle$, you can always decompose this in terms of the eigenvector basis, i.e. there exist some numbers $\alpha_i$ such that
$$
|b\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|\phi_i\rangle.
$$
Now, everything that we are doing is linear, so if we know the action on the $|\phi_i\rangle$, we know the action on $|b\rangle$:
$$
|b\rangle\longrightarrow\sum_i\alpha_i|\phi_i\rangle|\theta_i\rangle.
$$
About $|\Psi_0\rangle$ (at least a little bit of intuition): Usually when you perform phase estimation for something like Shor's algorithm, your initial state is $|000\ldots 0\rangle$ and is first acted upon by $H$ on every qubit. So, really, we could write the state at that point as the input, and it would be
$$
|\Psi_{\text{original}}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\sum_{\tau=0}^{T-1}|\tau\rangle
$$
where $\tau$ is just the decimal representation of a $t$ bit number, if you're doing the phase estimation with a register of $t$ bits. This choice of initial state does a particular job -- whatever the eigenvalue that's being measured, if it isn't exactly one of the phases that's detected by the phase estimation, you are still guaranteed that with high probability you get the best approximation to the eigenvalue. In HHL, this is not exactly what you care about. For eigenvalues $\lambda$, you're going to be computing $\frac{1}{\lambda}$ in the inversion step. So we care far more about making sure we get the small $\lambda$ terms accurate than we do the large $\lambda$ terms if we're trying to keep the overall error down. Thus, the idea of using a slightly different initial state is to try and minimise this error.

Thanks for your explanation! Could you please clarify, in case of eigenvalue combination $$
|b\rangle=\sum_i\alpha_i|\phi_i\rangle.
$$ - why $\alpha$ does not affect of the eigenvalue estimation? The state is already not an eigenvector. And from here the second question arises also: seems like we assume from beginning that $|b\rangle$ is a combination of operator's eigenvectors - then, after QPE stage the $|b\rangle$ register is not changed, right?

An operator's eigenvectors always form an orthonormal basis. So you can always decompose any state in terms of those eigenvectors. It's not an assumption!

After the QPE stage, the $|b\rangle$ register is changed. It is certainly no longer simply in the state $|b\rangle$. It is entangled with the other register.

Why don't the $\alpha_i$ affect things? It's a basic property of quantum mechanics. You can see this for any unitary operation $U$: $U(\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle)=\alpha(U|0\rangle)+\beta(U|1\rangle)$.
